# Can hulks be shut down psychically?

Tags: comics, the-incredible-hulk, psychic, marvel

Clearly the Phoenix Five [failed to do so](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21894/3804), but it's possible that could just be due to them being juiced up with cosmic radiation which the Red Hulk eats for breakfast.

I know similar power-houses like the Juggernaut have been brought down by psychic attacks, but it isn't clear whether hulks are as susceptible. For one I'd imagine the Green Hulk is too angry, but I don't know about the many, many others.

Can hulks be shut down psychically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Hulk has not been attacked by many people with mental powers. The reasons for this vary widely but the central tenets are:

- The Hulk is known to be powered by rage. Almost all good psionic users in the Marvel Universe know this. They avoid the Hulk because his rage is painful to them and is best avoided. Rage also acts as a barrier against psychic assault as Wolverine can attest.
- Most psionic abilities require the target to be willing or at least unsuspecting, for any serious mental control to take place.
- Even a willing Hulk's mind is a difficult place to work and Jean Grey discovers this when she attempts to release the World-breaker Hulk against the power of the psionic entity Onslaught (a psychic amalgam of Magneto's unleashed electromagnetic powers and Charles Xavier's psychic puissance).

[image]

I would say most of the Hulks would be relatively immune to psychic assault for the very same reason, their rage prevents the psychic from getting a good handle on the vulnerable parts of their psyche. This does not mean a surprise or coordinated attack made by powerful psychics might not have the desired result.

Comment: Are all hulks powered by rage though? Rulk? She-hulk(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Well Apocalypse beat Hulk pretty easily, I'm thinking that was a combined assault, physical and mental, considering Apocalypse's range of powers, and the status quo of Hulk being near-impossible to shut down by physical means alone

Also, you're asking can he be shut down psychically, well Apocalypse controlled him as one of his Four Horsemen. So I'm thinking that was a psychic shutdown. Or maybe his Celestial powers? Regardless we have precedent of Hulk being controlled by someone (even though Banner wasn't present in Hulk at the time so perhaps that was a large factor in that whole story)

Comment: Which story is this?