# Has The Hulk ever been controlled using mind-control?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk

I'm interested to know whether or not [**The Hulk**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_%28comics%29) has ever been controlled using any form of mind-control, or ever been an 'enemy', but not of his own volition.

**Has The Hulk ever been controlled using mind-control?** Or something similar?

---

<sup>**Not part of the question**, but I ask this as I'm interested to know personally what to make of the new *[Avengers: Age of Ultron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/)* possibilities. I'm not asking what he's doing in the trailer, but **what has possibly happened in the past**.</sup>

Comment: Hulk got mind controlled in Earth's mightiest hero by enchantress.

Comment: While it wasn't direct mind control, I think the Hulk was under Loki's influence on the helicarrier in *The Avengers*.

Comment: I recall a DC cross-over where I believe Lex Luthor had a swarm of nano-bots constantly buzzing around the Hulk, driving him crazy so he caused a lot of damage and couldn't be calmed.

Comment: Annoying him to no end isn't really the same thing as being mind controlled.

Comment: Related: [Can hulks be shut down psychically?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21895/21267)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Hulk has traditionally shown a specific resistance to mind control. [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Hulk_(Bruce_Banner)#ixzz3XX1HgBqZ) mentions this explicitly.

> **The Hulk has shown a high resistance to** physical damage nearly regardless of the cause, and has also shown resistance to extreme temperatures, **mind control**, nuclear explosions, poisons, and all diseases. In addition to the regeneration of limbs, vital organs, and damaged or destroyed areas of tissue at an amazing rate. The Hulk also has superhuman endurance.

He does, however, only have a "high resistance", and has been known to be placed under mind control.

In [*The Incredible Hulk #404*](http://marvel.wikia.com/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_404), for example, The Hulk is under the control of Mentallo.

*Bruce Banner* has also been shown to be susceptible.

In Defenders #19, [Dr Strange takes control of Bruce Banner's mind](http://clarmindcontrol.blogspot.com/2013/05/doctor-strange-doesnt-mind-controlling.html) to defuse a bomb.

Comment: Yet, Scarlet Witch can control him in MCU? There must be government laws to enforce consistency. There are possibilities that fans can suicide...

Comment: The Scarlet Witch's powers [have been altered for the MCU](http://www.newsarama.com/23937-whedon-confirms-scarlet-witch-power-changes-for-avengers-age-of-ultron.html).

Comment: As always, as plot demands.

Comment: Also, Loki controlled him (after first separating Bruce Banner from The Hulk) in Hulk vs. Thor. Animated movie, not comics, but still...

Comment: +1 I was in the process of writing a question on why they couldn't use the Scarlet Witch to calm the Hulk once she became an Avenger in Age of Ultron. Your Joss Whedon link and this answer answered my question.

Comment: @evilangel It's my understanding that she didn't really control him, she only aggravated his emotions.

Comment: Way back in Hulk #3, Rick Jones has control of the hulk. There's a comic where Dr Doom brainwashes Banner, can't remember the # right now.

Answer (score 0):

Apocalypse had him as one of his Four Horsemen, so I'm going to point to that. Though Banner wasn't present at the time. Still though

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange.  Adding a link to support your answer would improve your chance of having your answer accepted.