# Why does Red Hulk lose his mustache when powering up?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

Red Hulk doesn't have a mustache. But as seen in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21894/27831), he has a mustache in mere-mortal mode. Why? Doesn't "Hulking out" scale up your normal body? Is he using a mustache-wig in normal mode?

Yes, I know that I'm writing about a character that violates mass/energy conservation but only complaining about him also violating hair conservation.

Comment: ***"It's because Red Hulks is not cool and only cool people get to rock an awesome mustache.  Hence the cosmic powers of awesome remove his mustache whenever he transforms."*** - http://www.comicvine.com/thunderbolt-ross/4005-3457/forums/his-mustache-547845/

Comment: Never let it be said that we don’t ponder the big, important questions here on scifi.SE.

Comment: Out of canon, the answer is probably because the identity of Red Hulk was a secret for months before his true identity was revealed.

Comment: The gamma transformation seems to have a sort of template for what the final product is regardless of what the person looks like in their "calm" state.  It's that sort of cromagnon brow, shaggy dark hair, no neck, big hands and feet look.  Although didn't Banner shave his head and that translated in to a bald Hulk once?

Comment: I agree with @krillgar - the actual answer from a writing standpoint is that the mustache would have made guessing his identity too easy. As far as I know, only one character has that particular kind of mustache. Sorry, make that two (Dum-Dum Dugan being the other).

Comment: I don't know what the exact mechanism is but it's done pretty consistently as far as I know. Maestro is always shown with a bald head with just hair on the back of his head, although his Banner counterpart has a full head of hair. As for violating mass/energy conservation, the Official Marvel Handbook has alluded to an extradimensional source for the Hulk's extra mass. That's where he's shunting it while he's reverting to Banner. Maybe that's where Rulk's moustache and Maestro's hair go when they hulk out & that is where they automatically come back from when they revert to their human selves.

Comment: Extradimensional sources as plot devices are Marvel's go to workaround for mass/energy conservation anyway. The mechanism for what Pym particles do is pretty much the same as that of the Hulk, albeit with a definite bigger range, at least in practice, for shunting and gaining mass. Even Cyclops's optic blasts originate from an extradimensional source for that matter.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/232170/58193).

Answer (score 3):

Well, his hair and nail color also seem to change, along with his skin color and complexion/size (of course!). He doesn't seem to have hair on arms, chest or legs (and I don't want to find what is under the *[indestructible pants](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicPants)*), so maybe this "hair recessing mystery" **is just part of the Hulk transformation process' magic altogether**.

If we suspend the disbelief for the "mass/energy conservation" process, could be safe to do so for the "hair conservation".

Comment: I felt that 'indestructible pants' needed a TV tropes link :-)

Comment: And his eyes. Don't forget his eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This explains it.

http://uk.askmen.com/entertainment/special_feature_250/250_special_feature.html

> Human hair is a simple thing made of keratin and [b]dead skin
>   cells[/b].

http://www.experienceproject.com/question-answer/Are-Hair-And-Fingernails-Considered-Living-Tissue-Or-Matter-Biologically/269038

> Are hair and fingernails considered "living" tissue or matter
>   biologically?
>
> Except for the roots, they're dead.

As these cells are already dead when he powers up he loses it. During Aaron's Incredible Hulk run, Hulk took a gamma bomb at point blank range and lost all his hair - as the cells are dead they didn't regenerate.